# Content Provider, CONTENT_FILTER_URI... How to form the filtering URI correctly?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I have several questions related to the [official LoaderManager example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) when implementing filtering in an application (i.e. SQLite database, using Content Provider, using CONTENT_URI when no filtering is used, or forming the URI for filtering via concatenation of the CONTENT_FILTER_URI and the content of the `mCurFilter` variable.

Fistly, *I need confirmation, that I understand the filtering URI correctly.* Earlier, I did use the `CONTENT_URI` and set the `selection`, `selectionArgs`, and `sortOrder` when creating `new CursorLoader(...)` in the `onCreateLoader` method of the activity that implements `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>`. I did not understand why others use a special CONTENT_FILTER_URI.

The official example passes `null` for the `selectionArgs`, and the filter value is probably extracted as `filter = uri.getLastPathSegment();` and added used for the `selectionArgs`. In my case, I am passing `null` also for the `selection` and forming it in the content provider like:

```
selection = ProductTable.COLUMN_NAME + " like ?";
selectionArgs = new String[]{ "%" + filter +"%" };
```

*My understanding now is* that:

- The *filter* value can be used also other ways than simply put to a simple and single  SQL command, and this is the reason to use the `CONTENT_FILTER_URI`.
- The `CONTENT_FILTER_URI` makes getting the information more abstract, i.e. less SQL specific, more web-service like access to the data.

With respect to that, *I am still confused why also the `sortOrder` is not expressed in the URI* somehow. Is it a kind of tradeoff? (I hope the official example simply does not take a slopy approach, and there is real reason to form the `select` argument outside the content provider.)

*Should I always parse the user-entered filter value?* The reason is that a user can enter whatever filter value -- also the forbidden characters can be inserted. This way the unknown URI path can be formed and the URI may not be recognized. Or even worse, there may be a chance that some kind of SQL injection can be done, or at least the application can be crashed. Am I too paranoic when thinking about URI and the injection errors? Are there some rules or tools mentioned at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/) or elsewhere that are related to the problem?